# How to renew SFDC Expiring Certificate?

Tags: certificates

I got a notification,the notification is

You have one or more certificates in your Salesforce org [NAME + Orgid] that will expire soon. Please review the list below and visit Certificate and Key Management from Setup to make an update.

- SelfSignedCert_20Jan2014_160057, Self-Signed, expires on 1/20/2016. Warning: This certificate will expire in 30 day(s)
  which activity we need to perform for the certificate renew?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88397/how-to-renew-salesforce-ca-signed-certificate

Answer (score 11):

Rename current certificate, then create a new self-signed certificate with a previous name. This way you won't need to update your code references, but might still need to update configuration (single sign on and/or API client certificate).

You can find these under `Security Controls > Certificate and Key Management`.

Comment: What do you mean by update configuration (single sign on and/or API client certificate) , how can i do that ? is there any concret tutorial ?
Thanks

Comment: @Mus if you are using cert with SSON, you should check whether reference is still there after you replace the cert.

Comment: @dzh - why worry about keeping the cert name the exact same?

Answer (score 7):

The steps above seem to be incomplete:  I tried to delete the old certificate and it said it was still being used.  Here is my take:

**Email Warning:   Sandbox: SFDC Expiring Certificate Notification**
If you get an email with the following Subject Line, follow the instructions below:  Note:  The instructions in this link seem to be incomplete. [How to renew SFDC Expiring Certificate?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118330/how-to-renew-sfdc-expiring-certificate)

1. Open sandbox.  Go to Setup → Certificate and Key Management
2. Rename the expiring certificate with the suffix “-old”
3. Create a new certificate with the name of the expired certificate.  Keeping the name intact somehow helps reduce maintenance if you have references to this certificate in code.
4. Go to Single Sign-On Settings.
5. Check each record listed.   Note:   Click on the “Identity Connect” link (not Edit) and view what certificate it has assigned to it.  (if you click Edit you cannot see the assignment easily).
6. If the record lists the old certificate press Edit.  Assign the Request Signing Certificate Field to the New Certificate (with the previous name).
   7 Go back to the Certificate and Key Management and delete the expiring  certificate

Comment: I could not find the "Identity Connect" link(Step 5). Not sure if it was removed by SF. Thanks.

Comment: I did 1 through 3, however, I'm using this certificate in a "Named Credential". So, after issuing new certificate (and the old one remains with "-old" prefix), I went to "Named credentials :: Edit :: -> selected the new certificate in JWT Signing Certificate field (just where the old was)". Now, my callouts all fail with:

System.CalloutException: Unable to complete the JWT token exchange. Error: invalid_client. Error description: invalid client credentials.

What am I missing?…

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to update the certificate in Single Sign-On Settings. The new certificate will not be used until you do this.

1. Navigate to `Setup>Single Sign-On Settings`
2. Edit the Sign-On Setting that uses the expiring certificate
3. Select the newly-created certificate from the `Request Signing Certificate` drop down
4. Go back to `Setup>Certificate and Key Management`
5. Delete the Old Certificate

Answer (score 0):

I believe that certificates labeled like "*SelfSignedCert*__**Date**_**Number**" are created by Salesforce itself.

As I understood, mine "*SelfSignedCert_17Oct2022_*******" was created during Winter'23 release that occurred exactly on that day. It was used by Identity Provider, but there have been no Service Providers connected to it and no any other signs of its usage.
So I thought SF configured it just as default option, additional potential instrument for us to use.

Didn't bother to renew the certificate. Just removed the Identity Provider setting and then the certificate.